# SQL Finding a percentage of total of one column

Tags: sql, presto

For example I have a table of how many requests an employee gets each hour:

| Employee | Requests | Hour |
| --- | --- | --- |
| John | 12 | 12pm |
| Nancy | 5 | 12pm |
| John | 4 | 1pm |

I want to create a table that contains (i) the employee, (ii) the total number of requests they received across all hours, divided by total number of requests received by all employees.

So the resulting table would look like:

| Employee | Percent requests |
| --- | --- |
| John | 0.76 |
| Nancy | 0.24 |

Because:

sum of John's requests / total requests = (12+4)/(12+4+5)=0.76

and

sum of Nancy's requests / total requests = 5/(12+4+5)=0.24

I tried to sum the individual employee's requests while grouping by hour first, but I'm not sure how to incorporate the sum of the total requests into one command.

It is easy to find out what is the sum of the total requests, but I only know how to find it in a separate query first and then manually dividing each employee's total requests by the sum. I want to be able to do it in one query.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please have a look at [tour]. You may also want to check [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [ask], and how to create a [mcve]. Post the code you have tried and the errors you have received. Be as specific as possible as it will lead to better answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use window functions:

```
select employee, sum(requests) as total_requests,
       sum(requests) * 1.0 / sum(sum(requests)) over () as ratio
from t
group by employee;
```

The `* 1.0` is simply to avoid integer division (assuming that `requests` is an integer).

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```sql
WITH dataset AS (
  SELECT * 
  FROM 
    ( VALUES
      ('John',  12  ,'12pm'),
      ('Nancy', 5,  '12pm'),
      ('John',  4   ,'1pm')
       ) AS t (Employee,    Requests,   Hour)
) 

select  Employee,  cast(sum(Requests) as double) / (select sum(Requests) from dataset)
from dataset
group by Employee
```

Output:

| Employee | _col1 |
| --- | --- |
| Nancy | 0.23809523809523808 |
| John | 0.7619047619047619 |